# Forgot the password of wp-admin of my website

Tags: wordpress, azure

I have deployed Wordpress on Azure and forgot the password of wp-admin of my website.

Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: Do you have the database credentials with you that you entered when you created the Wordpress deployment on Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find `phpmyadmin` if you have one and from there, on the left side you can see the database that you have created for your website and you click on it. after that you have to find the databaseusername that you have created like wp_users. after that you will see a list of users of your website.[image] then click on the user you want to change the password of and click on the edit on the left side of the users name. from there change the `user_pass` value to what you want and choose `md5` for your `function`.after that click go
[image]

Comment: Do i need to install phpMyAdmin on my windows? I am using windows machine.

Comment: i think azure already contains phpmyadmin but if it doesnt maybe this helps https://sunithamk.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/how-to-use-phpmyadmin-for-your-azure-web-app/

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. as you have said. i have followed and found it. But password seems encrypted and it is not the one i was using. So how to see original password on can change?

Comment: Even i have changed user_pass with new password but i am not able to use the new on at mysite.com/wp-admin

Comment: you have to change the user_pass and you have to--> set function to md5 and then by clicking go you are changing the password and you can use the new password for your wordpress. but if you want to know what the hashed password is you can use online md5 decrypters to find what the hashed password is but i may warn you this is not a good way because the password might be hashed by a differed protocol

Comment: Damnn..Thank you so much! It worked! You saved me man! I owe you big thanks! :)

Comment: your welcome. please check this question as the answer (on the left side of my answer) and rate it up. than you very much

Answer (score 0):

md5 may not work with the latest versions as they have changed it. You can change the password by adding this function `wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );` into any of the theme templates and load it only once then remove it. WP has functions for almost everything we do in the gui.  More info at 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password

Answer (score 0):

*log into phpmyadmin
*select bitnami-wordpress database
*selct wp-users table
*run this query
UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_pass` = md5('yourpassword') WHERE `wp_users`.`ID` = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Goto https://HERE_GOES_YOUR_APP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings
and it should return a JSON which has WORDPRESS_ADMIN_USER and WORDPRESS_ADMIN_PASSWORD. It is especially useful if you lost both login and password